# Is there any group with these conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any infinite group $G$, such that $G^\prime$ is Abelian, and any Abelian and normal subgroup of $G$ is finite?
In other words:

1. $G^\prime$ is Abelian
2. $\forall H \trianglelefteq G$ : ($H$ is Abelian) $\Rightarrow |H| < \infty$

Comment: This doesn't make sense: "any finite Abelian and normal subgroup of G is finite".   *Any* finite subgroup of $G$ is finite.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes! It's duplicate.

Comment: Well, no problem. Is the answer there helping you ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I think this is a bit different, and the reason I answered this question is because I understood it as "Is there an infinite group $G$ such that every subgroup of $G$ is finite".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes;

consider the following group.

Let $p$ be a prime number, define 
$$Z(p^{\infty}):=\left\{\dfrac{m}{p^n} \mid  0\leq\dfrac{m}{p^n}<1\text{ and } m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\},$$ then $Z(p^{\infty})$ is an infinite abelian group under addition modulo 1. Furthermore, any proper subgroup of $Z(p^{\infty})$ is of the form $$G_k:=\left\{0,\dfrac{1}{p^k},\dfrac{2}{p^k}, \dots , \dfrac{p^k-1}{p^k}\right\}.$$

Comment: I have edited your LaTeX for clarity, and fixed the second fraction in $G_{k}$, please check whether it's what you intended.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti yes, thank you.